# SQL - Extracting an ID range for a packet of records

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table where I have about 40000000 records. Min(id) = 2 and max(80000000).

I would like create a automated script which will be running in a loop.
But I don't want to create about 80 iteration because a part of then will be empty.

Who knows how I can find range min(id) and max(id) for first iteration, and next?

I used mod but it doesn't work correctly:

```
SELECT MIN(ID), MAX(ID)
FROM (
SELECT mod(id,45), id FROM table
WHERE mod(id,45) = 0
GROUP BY mod(id,45), id
ORDER BY id desc
)
```

Because I want to:

```
first iteration has range for 1mln records: min(id) = 2 max(id) = 1 500 000
second iteration has range for 1 mln records: min(id)=1 550 000, max(id) = 5 000 000
and so on
```

Comment: MySQL or db2? Please remove unrelated tags

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy for whatever DBMS supporting ordered numbering of rows.

Db2.
Every SELECT returns 2 rows except the last one, which may return less rows.

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM MYTAB WHERE I BETWEEN ' || MIN (I) || ' AND ' || MAX (I) AS STMT
FROM 
(
  SELECT I, (ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY I) - 1) / 2 AS RN_
  FROM (VALUES 1, 9, 2, 7, 4) MYTAB (I)
) G
GROUP BY RN_
```

The result is:

| STMT |
| --- |
| SELECT * FROM MYTAB WHERE I BETWEEN 1 AND 2 |
| SELECT * FROM MYTAB WHERE I BETWEEN 4 AND 7 |
| SELECT * FROM MYTAB WHERE I BETWEEN 9 AND 9 |